# RelativeSource binding can't find Frame ancestor

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, navigation

I'm trying to pass as a `CommandParameter` the actual `Frame` object to which I'm applying the `Command`

**XAML**

```
<Frame NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" Source="{Binding TargetContentPage}">
       <i:Interaction.Triggers>
             <i:EventTrigger EventName="ContentRendered">
                    <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ContentRendered}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Frame}}"/>
             </i:EventTrigger>
       </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Frame>
```

**C#**

```
public RelayCommand<Frame> ContentRendered
{
     get
     {
          return new RelayCommand<Frame>(frame => frame.RemoveBackEntry());
     }
}
```

When running, a `NullReferenceException` is raised saying `frame` is null.
What is possibly wrong in the code above ?

Comment: Are you possibly missing Mode=FindAncestor?

Comment: @Clemens yep you are right, I missed that, please add it as an answer please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no ancestor/descendent relation between Frame and EventToCommand. Use an ElementName binding instead:

```
<Frame x:Name="frame" ...>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="ContentRendered">
            <command:EventToCommand
                Command="{Binding ContentRendered}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=frame}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Frame>
```